# calling a pl sql function issue

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Hello every one i just was told about this site today and i could use some help.
I have read the rules and i understand what i am doing code wise well we just started Pl sql last week before that i had only done basic sql. but now i am stuck on calling the function i made :/ i feel silly. It is a fairly straight forward function and i am sure it is correct as my sql teacher said 'it looks good at a glance' but she did not show me how to call the functions and i really want to see if it working.

I know how to call basic sql and functions  and pl sql with dbms.out but i draw a blank here, i remember her saying use **1** instead of employee_no in the select and its just two lines to call it please please can some one show me how to call what i made. I attached the ERD below too.

***(a)  to calculate and return the total number of different task-types a given employee has worked on.***

```
SHOW ERRORS

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION task_types(eno employee.employee_no%TYPE)
  RETURN NUMBER IS

  task_var task.task_type_no%TYPE;


  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_type_no)
    INTO task_var
    FROM employee e, task t, assignment a
    WHERE e.employee_no = a.employee_no
          AND a.task_id = t.task_id
          AND e.employee_no = eno;

    RETURN task_var;

  END;
```

Entity-relational diagram:

[image: the ERD]

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? (Plsql is Oracle.)

Comment: Ah thank you i put the wrong tag i am using oracle iSQL*plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function in SQL

```
select task_types(e.employee_no) as task_types
from employee e;
```

Or, if you know a specific employee number

```
select task_types(1) 
from dual;
```

Or in plsql

```
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(task_types(1));
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select task_types(your_employee_id) from dual;
```

As your_employee_id use any existing id or 1 mentioned by you in post.